# call function from js file inside php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I have a file like **"my_js_stuff.js"** which is looking like this :

```
function my_js_function() 
 {
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
 data: ({action : 'get_my_comments'}),
 success: function() {
  //Do stuff here
 }
 });
```

This file is included in my
 `<header>`like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js_stuff.js"></script>`

I want to call the function from **"my_js_stuff.js"** inside my php page, and I'm thinking to call it like  this:

```
<?php

<script type="text/javascript>
   $('.some-class').on('click', my_js_function()); // this is the function from the js file.
</script>

?>
```

Is this the correct way to call the function from the js file ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you want to write something "from PHP to browser" use the "echo" command (in PHP) like echo "<script> ... </script>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to call the function from the js file ?

`my_js_function()` is certainly the correct way to call it.

But, to pass the `function` so the event can call it later, you'll want to skip the calling parenthesis:

```
$('.some-class').on('click', my_js_function);
```

With them, it'll be called immediately and its `return` value will instead be passed to the event binding.

---

Also note that the `<script>` shouldn't be inside a `<?php ... ?>` block unless it's in a [string](http://php.net/string) being [`echo`](http://php.net/echo)ed.

```
<?php
    # ...
?>

<script>
    $('.some-class').on('click', my_js_function);
</script>

<?php
    # ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the technologies. Your JS is for the client side (browser) and the PHP is for the server side (business logic).

You cannot call a JS function from inside PHP.

However, assuming you want to communicate JS > PHP, you need to include the JS on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript?>
   $('.some-class').on('click', my_js_function()); // this is the function from the js file.
</script>
```

and your URL needs to match the PHP endpoint:

```
url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl, // This should be the path of your PHP file
```

Inside the php file you can get all the info as if it were a normal request:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['action'];
?>
```

This will return the $_GET['action'] var to your JS success function:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert('Received: ' + data);
}
```

Hopefully you can use this information to build what you need.

Comment: I don't know why, but I was thinking that is possible to call a js function inside PHP. Thank you for your response

Comment: I updated my answer to include some information for how the AJAX works with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but I'm not sure that's what you actually want to do. Javascript is executed on the client-side, whereas PHP is executed on the server. Your Ajax function makes a request (client-to-server) and fetches content from the server, such as dynamic content generated from a PHP file.

If what you're describing is really what you want to do, you need to `echo` your script snippet and enclose it in quotes.

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">/*js content*/</script>';

?>
```